# How can kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN be true and kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable be false

Tags: ios, reachability

In iOS reachability, synchronously checking the SCNetworkReachabilityFlags and getting a combination of flags which are:

- [kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachabilityflags/kscnetworkreachabilityflagsreachable?language=objc): 0
- [kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachabilityflags/kscnetworkreachabilityflagsiswwan): 1

According to Apple's documentation (but also the reachability implementations in other libraries such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m#L51)), kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN indicates it is available by a cellular network, but when this is true, the overall kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable should be true also.

This seems to happen only when you switch from Wifi to Mobile. (When you start on Mobile, it generates, correctly both flags as true).

Any ideas how this situation might be generated (new in 10.3.2?), or is my understanding of the flag meanings wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and the issue was that the user had disabled Mobile Data for the app in question

Comment: Although we also found that AFNetworking was not always firing events correctly -- (switching from AFNetworking for reachability status sorted us out)